# How I can set the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController as MainView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, abpeoplepickerview

Is it possible to show the whole contact list like the apple addressbook app?
Is there an UI from apple that I can use?
Or do I need to copy the complete contacts with ABAddressBook and build my own ListView?

I know there is the [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate)

I allready used the Picker with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self addContact];
}

-(void)addContact {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    return YES;
}
```

But actually I don’t want to open a Picker. I need to set this to the main view, without a cancle button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use just parts of it (well.. technically you could, but I dont think apple would like it :D)

you have to reproduuce it I fear